# css the float right option changed the selector

Tags: css, css-float

I make a simple selector like this:

[image]

when I make the `float:right`, I got this:

[image]

please see the red circle to know what is the problem.

#### css

```
/* The CSS */
select {
    padding:3px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    float:right;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ccc, 0 -1px #fff inset;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color:#888;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* Targetting Webkit browsers only. FF will show the dropdown arrow with so much padding. */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    select {padding-right:18px}
}

label {position:relative}
label:after {
    content:'<>';
    font:11px "Consolas", monospace;
    color:#aaa;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    right:8px; top:2px;
    padding:0 0 2px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
}
label:before {
    content:'';
    right:6px; top:0px;
    width:20px; height:20px;
    background:#f8f8f8;
    position:absolute;
    pointer-events:none;
    display:block;
}
```

the `float:right` that I changed, and that is making the problem, exist in the `select` in the `css`

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle with your HTML and CSS? It is easier to help you.

Comment: please be carful with the word `selector`. This is as custom select field like you titled it correctly in the image. Also your element is `inline-block` when you make it float, it will become a `block` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little tricky to identify without more HTML/CSS but it seems to be because the selection box and the element circled in red are two seperate elements and you've only floated one.

What you may want to do is wrap both in a `div` and apply `float:right` to this. This will mean that everything within the `div` is floated (both the selection box and the element encircled)